# Post file from silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, post, upload, http-post

I want to post file from Silverlight to server.

Currently in Silverlight I have `FileInfo myFile;`. On server side, I need this file to be in `Request.Files` collection.

My question is how to post myFile from Silverlight to the Server to be able to access it in Request.Files collection on server side?

Thank you.

Comment: you can try HttpClient and post the file

Comment: I was trying to install [HttpClient(http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http), but for some reason I couldn`t add references to the project after installation. It was saying that library was not built in Silverlight, so it couldn `t add the reference to the project. Instead I found other solution. Please read my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I used to post file stream to server.

```
private void LayoutRoot_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            _dropEventOccured = "Yes";
            FileInfo[] files = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as FileInfo[];

            MessageBox.Show(files.Length.ToString());

            //MessageBox.Show("Dropped");

            foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
            {
                _fileRead = "Yes";
                _file = fi;
                FileStream fs = _file.OpenRead();
                objByte = ReadFully(fs);
                fs.Close();
                Post();

            }
        }

 public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }


private void Post()
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = null;
            //request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost/ajax.aspx") as HttpWebRequest;
            //request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost/ajax.aspx") as HttpWebRequest;
            request = HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format("http://localhost/ajax.aspx?name={0}",_file.Name )) as HttpWebRequest;
            //request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
            request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
            request.Method = "POST"; // Doesn't work with "GET"
            request.ContentLength = objByte.Length;

            if (request.Method == "GET")
            {
                request.BeginGetResponse(this.GetRequestStreamCallback, request);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Posting...");
                request.BeginGetRequestStream(this.GetRequestStreamCallback, request);
            }


        }

        private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;

            using (Stream stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(result))
            {

                stream.Write(objByte, 0, objByte.Length);
                stream.Close();
            }
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
            //HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)result.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);
        }

        private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
                while (!request.HaveResponse)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
                Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

This is the code on server side:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
string saveTo = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/") + Request.QueryString["name"];
                // create a write stream
                FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(saveTo, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                // write to the stream
                ReadWriteStream(Request.InputStream, writeStream);
            }



            private void ReadWriteStream(Stream readStream, Stream writeStream)
            {
                int Length = 256;
                Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
                int bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
                // write the required bytes
                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
                }
                readStream.Close();
                writeStream.Close();
            }
```